# Vote Count Tallying

Tags: java

I was presented with the problem of creating a java program that tallies the votes of each individual candidate. We are supposed to use arrays; however, we were just taught them, and I am not quite following how to solve this.

The file we are supposed to read from is this:

4    7

2    10

3    2

3    4

4    5

5    6

7    9

0    12

1    2

3    45

6    9

55   19

-4   11

4    4

3    -21

The left column is the candidate number, and the right is the number of votes.

The first column can only be a whole number from 1-10. The second can be any positive value.
In the end, the program is supposed to add together the total votes cast for each candidate.

I think we need an array that goes something like: `int[] cands = new int[10]` It specifies the candidate number. However, I do not understand how to organize the values. Sorry if this seems jumbled..I am not sure how to explain this as I am slightly confused. Do I need more than just one array?

Here is a snippet of the directions:

> Each line in this file contains two numbers: the first is the candidate identifier (1-10) and the second is the number of votes that candidate received.   Your program will tally the number of votes per candidate using an array where each array entry represents a candidate.    Notice that each array entry acts as a accumulator of votes for that candidate.

Edit: This is what I have so far..

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

File file = new File("Tally.txt");
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
int[] cands = new int[10];
int cnt = 0;

while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    int cand = input.nextInt() - 1;
    int vote = input.nextInt();

    if ((cand >= 0 && cand < cands.length) && vote > 0) {
    cands[cand] += vote;
    }
}

System.out.println("Canidate:  \t  Votes:");
for (int index = 1; index < cands.length + 1; index++) {
    if (cnt < cands.length) {
    System.out.println("\t " + index + "\t\t" + cands[cnt]);
    cnt++;
    }
}
input.close();
}
```

}

However, once it reaches a negative value or a value higher than 10 in the file it throws all kinds of errors (such as java.util.NoSuchElementException). How can I avoid this?

Comment: Here's the problem with this question for me. You did a great job of thoroughly explaining the problem that was given to you by your teacher. I know how to solve it and I could give you the answer. However, I don't see that you've put any effort into solving it yourself. Someone will probably give you the answer, looking to gain some reputation, but you'll be far better off if you find a resource and teach yourself, or ask the teacher for help, and then do the problem on your own (and come ask for help then, after trying it and getting an error).

Comment: Let's play the "what if" game. What if, as you noted, you had a pair of arrays? How would you try to code that?

Comment: First split problem into small chunks of problem. Google for each of them. possible here is the order... how to read a file content. Then either find out how to use scanner to read numbers one after the other, this can either be done by using Scanner or read entire file into string and split it multiple times to get all the numbers read into arrays. You can either create two arrays to store candidates and votes. Or you can use Hashmap where key would be candidate id and value would be votes. While trying to add a candidate, check if the candidate already exists using map.contains, add if it is

Comment: An array has two elements - the INDEX of the array, and the VALUE stored there.  Think about how you can use both of these elements to accomplish what you need

Comment: Hey guys, I think I am starting to figure this out. I added a chunk of my code to my edit.

Comment: Since you can have 10 candidates you must allocate the array with 10 elements and not nine as you have done in your code

Answer (score 0):

You've done an excellent job with the code you've just added! Only two things left to fix.

First, your `int[] cands` is of length 9, but you have 10 candidates. If you have a `new int[9]` then it has indices from 0 to 8, because there are 9 and they start at 0. You should think about what happens when you encounter candidate 10.

Secondly, this is your description of the file:

> The first column can only be a whole number from 1-10. The second can be any positive value. In the end, the program is supposed to add together the total votes cast for each candidate.

It's clear from this that there shouldn't be any negative numbers to encounter, or any candidate numbers greater than 10! But the file, as you've given it, goes badly wrong on the last four lines: a candidate number of 55, one of -4, and a vote count of -21. So either the file doesn't match the description of the problem (in which case you need to go back and complain), or there's something you haven't told us about what you're supposed to do with lines that don't match the spec. (But in fact your code looks as though it does a great job of ignoring lines that don't match.)

Comment: Thank you! The lines that don't match the spec should just be ignored and move onto the next ints. I am going to add my more complete code now as it has a little more to it.